# Java Non-blocking channels, Selector and interestOps

Tags: java, events, select, nio

When I get OP_CONNECT event I call finishConnect() and update interestOps:

```
key.interestOps(key.interestOps() & ~SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT | SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

But in a next iteration(selector.select(..)) I again get OP_CONNECT event, although key.interestOps does not contain OP_CONNECT event.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which way do you  get OP_CONNECT event? I know only one way - from key.interestOps(), so that key.interestOps()&OP_CONNECT != 0. Вut you said `key.interestOps does not contain OP_CONNECT`, then where did you get that event?

Comment: I use key.isConnectable().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, all I need - it is remove used SelectionKey from a set of selectedKeys.